# Sort an array of object using string parameter in Swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, swift3

I have to sort an array of object using one parameter. I have created an entity, below is my JSON :

```
{
"Name": "Amit",
"Progress": "38",
"Color": "red",
},
  {
"Name": "Sonu",
"Progress": "70",
"Color": "green",
}
```

Below is my entity class:

```
class Scoreboard {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var scoreboardName: String? = ""
    var scoreboardProgress: String? = "0"
    var scoreboardColor: String? = ""        
}
```

This JSON data I have pass into table, The problem is How can I do sorting based on 'Progress'?

I tried below code:

```
scoreboardArray = scoreboardArray.sorted(by: {($0.scoreboardProgress() < $1.scoreboardProgress())})
```

But it's not working. Please anyone suggest me.

Comment: Like Sh_Khan said, remove the optional (`?`) if you are giving default value to variables. It is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try

```
scoreboardArray = scoreboardArray.sorted {
   Int($0.scoreboardProgress!)! < Int($1.scoreboardProgress!)! 
}
```

also if you assign a default value , it's better to remove `?`

Irrelevant but why not use `Decodable`

```
class Scoreboard : Decodable {
```

Comment: @user2786. be warned that if `scoreboardProgress ` contains a string value that can't be converted into Int, this code will crash

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz **scoreboardProgress** has a default value

Comment: Well, `scoreboardProgress ` can be assigned such a string value accidentally or as a result of error. I just try to remain on safe side, in case anything goes wrong.